# How to use the DSN from ODBC set up on computer with SQLConnection object

Tags: sql

I have been using the ADODB.Connection object to connect to our databases. I have begun using the SQLConnection object instead because it is more friendly with DataGridView controls.

The connection string for connection to the ADODB.Connection object is similar to this: `DSN=Foo;UID=Bar;PWD=123456;App=Baz`.

The connection string for the SQLConnection object is similar to this: `Data Source=Foo; Initial Catalog=Bar; User ID=Baz; Password=123456`

I prefer specifying the database using the user's DSN, that way each user connects to their local database that is configured in their ODBC. Using the SQLConnection object, it appears I have to specify the database name directly (Data Source, Initial Catalog).

I can manually write some code at the beginning of the app to fetch the name myself and use it throughout, but I'd like to be able to do this through the connection string if possible.

Is there a way that I can alter the connection string for the SQLConnection object to use the DSN that is configured instead?

Comment: What is your language or application layer and the RDMS? It looks like SQL Server. Also, please explain *each user connects to their local database*? Ideally, users should be using their own FrontEnd apps/scripts to connect to **one** BackEnd database.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/